# How to listen for clicks in fragment inside an activity in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am making an app in which there is a need for listening for click events on widgets of fragment .
In my app :
I set the default fragment for my activity to fragmentOne and i want to change the fragment of activity when someone clicks on a widget in fragmentOne i want to change the fragment of activity from fragmentOne to fragmentTwo.
Here's my main activity xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wordpress.tbkj.app_name.LoginSignupActivity">


    <fragment
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/login_signup_fragment"
        android:name="com.wordpress.tbkj.app_name.LoginFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here's my activity code :

```
public class LoginSignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_signup);
    }
}
```

when i launch this activity fragmenOne is visible.
please comment if anyone wants some other code.

Comment: Can you share some code? In a fragment you can also use setOnClickListener method on views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define an interface that the activity implements. For example:

```
public interface CoolFragmentListener {
    void someCoolWidgetActionClicked();
}

public class LoginSignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CoolFragmentListener  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_signup);
    }

    public void someCoolWidgetActionClicked() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        // Use the new instance pattern instead of directly instantiating your fragment.
        YourNewCoolFragment fragment = YourNewCoolFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Inside your fragment, you would have an object that implements the interface "CoolFragmentListener." This is usually done in the onAttach lifecycle.

```
public class YourNewCoolFragment extends Fragment {
    private CoolFragmentListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceOf CoolFragmentListener) {
            // context in this case is your activity, which implements CoolFragmentListener
            listener = (CoolFragmentListener) context;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coolstuff, container, false);

        // Assuming that your fragment has a Button with the id R.id.button
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.someCoolWidgetActionClicked();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

One more thing, instead of embedding your fragment inside your activity's layout in the code you shared, you should have a container view that the FragmentManager can add your new Fragment into. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wordpress.tbkj.app_name.LoginSignupActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This means that you would have to add your first fragment programmatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good description at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. In my opinion the transition of fragments is well described in the following:

> At any time while your activity is running, you can add fragments to your activity layout. You simply need to specify a ViewGroup in which to place the fragment.
>   To make fragment transactions in your activity (such as add, remove, or replace a fragment), you must use APIs from FragmentTransaction. You can get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction 
=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

> You can then add a fragment using the add() method, specifying the fragment to add and the view in which to insert it. For example:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

> The first argument passed to add() is the ViewGroup in which the fragment should be placed, specified by resource ID, and the second parameter is the fragment to add.